# Xero Auth 2.0 API status 403

Tags: reactjs, postman, xero-api

I am trying to create an invoice and send it after via the email api.

After I authenticate i am able to get https://api.xero.com/connections

When I try to create the invoice i do the following in Postman
POST: https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Invoices
The response i get is the following

{
"Type": null,
"Title": "Forbidden",
"Status": 403,
"Detail": "AuthenticationUnsuccessful",
"Instance": "",
"Extensions": {}
}

In my environmental variables my scope is offline_access accounting.transactions openid profile email
Should I have something in states? I so what should be the value if not what could be my issue?

I've tried the below
Ensuring that all environmental variables are correct.
Re Authenticate and test if i am actually connected
Ensure that the correct token is selected and updated